# What is the difference between Apache Traffic Server and regular Apache Web Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

Can one use the Apache Traffic Server and not have to use Apache Web Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start with, the "Apache" name is there to show that it's under Apache Foundation control, as it's stated on the web site: ["...Formerly a commercial product, Yahoo! donated it to the Apache Foundation, and it is now an Apache TLP."](http://trafficserver.apache.org/)

Also, from there - this is not a web server, but a proxy server.

So, to answer your question - to serve web pages you need Apache Web Server.

If you need proxy, you can use either Traffic server, or another proxy server like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).

If you need a reverse proxy, you can use either Apache Trafic Server, [Apache Web Server](https://httpd.apache.org/), [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/), [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/)